# Tour vs Path in graph theroy

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

English is not my mother tongue so I don´t know exactly wich is the difference between a tour and path in graphs theory context. I think that in both cases it is a way throught various vertex or points. Is this correct?

Comment: Usually, a path connects two vertices without repeat.
A tour goes though all vertices.

Comment: So the difference is if vertices are repeated?

Comment: All vertices -- tour.  Some vertices -- path.  Neither repeats a vertex.

Comment: Seems that a tour is a clycle according to this phrase in wikipedia :"A Hamiltonian cycle, Hamiltonian circuit, vertex tour or graph cycle is a cycle that visits each vertex exactly once (except for the vertex that is both the start and end, which is visited twice)." Is this incorrect in wikipedia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Walk - A sequence of vertices and edges, where the edges connect the adjacent vertices in the sequence

Tour - a walk with no repeated edges

Path - a walk with no repeated vertices

Source: CS 70 MT1 Review Spring 2018 @ UC Berkeley

Comment: can you link to the cs70 review?

Answer (score 1):

A path is a walk with no repeated vertices.

A trail is a walk with no repeated edges.

A tour is a walk that visits every vertex returning to its starting vertex. A tour could visit some vertices more than once. If you visit them exactly once, then the tour is a Hamiltonian cycle.

A cycle is a walk in which the end vertex is the same as the start vertex and no other vertex is visited more than once.